# change mysql table structure in production server

Tags: mysql

i have a table `sent_laundry` in mysql database in production server with column `first_wash` and `rewash` as below:

| first_wash | rewash |
| --- | --- |
| 121 | 124 |
| null | 125 |

i would like to change the structure into as below:

| wash_type | laundry_id |
| --- | --- |
| FirstWash | 121 |
| Rewash | 124 |
| Rewash | 125 |

I am trying to achieve:

1. table structure migrate (Successful)
2. without lossing data (Failed)

What i've tried:

I've changed table column locally and backed-up. And i have restored it in a local `test_scheme`.
Now, tables in 2 schemes have exactly the same columns, which is the `wash_type` and `laundry_id`. But the data in `test_scheme` has replaced with the data in the source/original scheme.

If i use the same way to restore table in production server, i will loss my real user's data.
May i know practical way to migrate table without data loss in my case?

Fyi: I am using the "data export" in MySQLWorkbench to backup table. and the "data import" in MySQLWorkbench to restore table.

Anyone who have idea, please share with me.

PS: Sorry i couldn't describe my question any better. Still learning to rephrase question in a way that people can understand better.

Comment: Create new table and replace old table with it.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- Create new table and fill it with data
CREATE TABLE new_table (wash_type VARCHAR(255), laundry_id INT)
SELECT 'FirstWash' wash_type, first_wash laundry_id 
FROM data_table
WHERE first_wash IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Rewash', rewash
FROM data_table
WHERE rewash IS NOT NULL;

-- drop old table
DROP TABLE data_table;

-- rename new table
RENAME TABLE new_table TO data_table;
```

Now backup `data_table` on test server, drop existing table on the production and restore from backup.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, have lead me to the direction. I got more column in table actually,  think i need study more to make sql script works. Thank you.